# How can I collect values from a mutableSharedFlow in a unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines

The following test doesn't pass. The string "before adding XXX" is never printed.

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun testFoo() = runBlocking {
        val testCoroutineScope = TestCoroutineScope().apply {
            pauseDispatcher() // This needs to be here because the actual test handles time.
        }
        val sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
        val values = mutableListOf<Int>()
        println("before launch")
        val job = testCoroutineScope.launch {
            println("before collect")
            sharedFlow.collect {
                println("before adding $it")
                values.add(it)
            }
        }
        println("before emits")
        sharedFlow.emit(1)
        sharedFlow.emit(2)
        testCoroutineScope.runCurrent()
        assertEquals(mutableListOf(1, 2), values)
        job.cancel()
    }
```

I would like to have a way to `emit` values once the collect part is handled. I can't set a `replay` value, nor can I use an `onSubscription` because that would change the business logic.

Adding `delay` or `yield` don't seem to make any difference so it might not be a racing condition.

The test passes if `pauseDispatcher()` is commented.

My understanding was that `emit` would suspend until the collect lambda were called.

Answer (score 2):

The way I solved it is via `extraBufferCapacity` and one more `testCoroutineScope.runCurrent()`

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun testFoo() = runBlocking {
        val testCoroutineScope = TestCoroutineScope().apply {
            pauseDispatcher()
        }
        val sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>(
            extraBufferCapacity = 2 // Without it, sharedFlow.emit won't have a space to save data. It will be collected
                                    // next time there's a testCoroutineScope.runCurrent()
        )
        val values = mutableListOf<Int>()
        println("before launch")
        val job = testCoroutineScope.launch {
            println("before collect")
            sharedFlow.collect {
                println("before adding $it")
                values.add(it)
            }
        }
        testCoroutineScope.runCurrent() // Allows the previous launch to start collecting

        println("before emits")
        sharedFlow.emit(1)
        sharedFlow.emit(2)
        testCoroutineScope.runCurrent()

        assertEquals(mutableListOf(1, 2), values)
        job.cancel()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Turns out my initial attempt wasn't bulletproof either, a race condition still existed, here's my revised solution, so far so good:

```kotlin
    val msf = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
    runBlocking {
        val job1 = GlobalScope.launch {
            msf
                .onStart {
                    println("${Thread.currentThread().name} - on start ")
                }
                .onEach { println("got $it") }
                .collect()
        }
        val job2 = launch {
            msf.subscriptionCount
                .filter { it > 0 }
                .onEach {
                    msf.emit(42)
                    cancel()
                }
                .collect()
        }
        delay(100)
        job1.cancel()
        println(job2)
    }
    println("${Thread.currentThread().name} - escaped!")
```

Old solution (incorrect):

```kotlin
    runBlocking {
        val msf = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
        val d = CompletableDeferred<Boolean>()
        launch {
            msf
                .onStart {
                    d.complete(true)
                }
                .onEach { println("got $it") }
                .collect()
        }
        d.join()
        msf.emit(42)
    }
```

using the `invokeOnCompletion()` handler cannot use suspended functions, using it with `tryEmit()` did not work for me (returns true but does nothing).